# Using a background image on a flot diagram/excanvas in IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, background, flot, excanvas

I'm trying to use the excanvas/JQuery based "Flot" plugin but would like to use a background image. At the moment however there is a bug that means it's not possible to set a background image to the canvas using CSS - the bug is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=40) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=125).

Has anyone managed to get around this bug? It's incredibly frustrating as using CSS to provide a background image to a canvas appears to be valid in every other browser; but not using IE and excanvas!

Any help would be appreciated! I've tried nested divs and more - and I'm running out of ideas!
Thanks in advance

Edit:
There's a possible workaround here - http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=129 - but it seems a bit outdated as a lot of the flot code isn't the same anymore. I guess it does give me something to start with however! If anybody has an easier solution I'd be happy to hear it!

Comment: that flot bug #129 seems like your best bet.  The code has changed a fair bit from that example, but the code is centered around the `draw()` function call, which still exists, and so do the bits of other code mentioned...

Comment: @Ryley Yeah, I've looked into that but as the codebase has changed so much I will have to take a really deeper look into things!